# need a query to get the following two select with one connection to mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to get the count(calmness)  from a table entity_epoch_data in mysql twice :

where column of calmness>0 and calmness<0

so now I connect to database twice as follow:

```
SELECT count(calmness) FROM omid.entity_epoch_data where calmness<0;

SELECT count(calmness) FROM omid.entity_epoch_data where calmness>=0;
```

I am wondering if I can combine these two query and get the result back as one table with one connection?

I tried this but did not work:

```
select c1,c2 from (

SELECT count(calmness) as c1 FROM omid.entity_epoch_data where calmness<0,

SELECT count(calmness) as c2 FROM omid.entity_epoch_data where calmness>=0);
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using `SUM()` with an expression,when using `SUM()` within expression it evaluates it to true/false i.e 1/0 based on the result of expression ,note you using aggregate function without grouping them this will result in a single row

```
SELECT 
 SUM(calmness < 0) c1,
 SUM(calmness >= 0)  c2
FROM omid.entity_epoch_data ;
```

Comment: Interesting,Just a question, sum plays a role of count here. I dont understand why (but it works correctly). Can you explain it?

Comment: @HamedMinaee as i explained in my answer if you use any condition/expression in sum the result will be a boolean 1 or zero so sum will work as a count based on these conditions you provide